# How to apply code to sheet that is not the active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried variations of `For Each Ws in...` but can't get my code to work on any sheet but the active one.

I have separate subs for each sheet but want them all in the one sub.

```vb
Sub NSWUpdate()
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In Names
        If Mid(n.RefersTo, 7, 2) = "$Y" Then n.Delete
    Next n
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Set Ws = Worksheets("NSOH")
    Set StartCell = Ws.Range("W12")
  
    Worksheets("NSOH").UsedRange
    LastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  
    Ws.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
End Sub


Sub VICUpdate()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Set Ws = Worksheets("VSOH")
    Set StartCell = Range("W12")
  
    LastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  
    Ws.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False

    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In Names
        If Mid(n.RefersTo, 8, 1) = "Y" Then n.RefersTo = n.RefersTo & "#"
    Next n
End Sub
```

The third sub is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your sheets NSOH,VSOH separately such as

```
Dim NSOH As Worksheet,VSOH as Worksheet

Set NSOH= Worksheets("NSOH")
Set VSOH= Worksheets("VSOH")
```

Then when setting your start cell assign it to a specific sheet

```
Set StartCell = NSOH.Range("W12")
```

You can do this for all referencing in the project and should be able to run it in one sub.

Comment: Thank you tech! It makes some sense and I think I am close, but struggling with setting the Ws.Range object (I think that is the issue). Getting a run time error 91 on `Ws.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select`

Comment: Where I'm up to
`Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NStartCell As Range
Dim QStartCell As Range
Dim VStartCell As Range
Dim NSOH As Worksheet, QSOH As Worksheet, VSOH As Worksheet

Set NSOH = Worksheets("NSOH")
Set QSOH = Worksheets("QSOH")
Set VSOH = Worksheets("VSOH")

 Set NStartCell = NSOH.Range("W12")
  
 Worksheets("NSOH").UsedRange
 LastRow = NSOH.Cells(NSOH.Rows.Count, NStartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  
 Ws.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select
 Selection.CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
    
Set QStartCell = QSOH.Range("W12")` etc

Comment: You havent set Ws as a worksheet. Remove it altogether and say which Range are you working

Comment: Thank you again, can you please give me an example? Do you mean just have `Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select` ?

Comment: where you say  Dim ws as worksheet you need to set ws as either vsoh or nsoh. The error you are getting means its looking at Ws.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow), but has no idea what ws is. When you deal with worksheets theres always the part where you define it first with Dim, then set it as one of your sheet names. Its not always necessary to do this, but it ensures your code wont shred your sheet should you have the wrong sheet open when you run it. Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select needs to be VSOH.Range("X12:Y" & LastRow).Select or vice versa depending on which one you need this line to be done